# Change the default video player

Tags: apps, video, system-apps

I'm really confused about the default video-player solution which is used for example by the IE or the Facebook app. It's not possible to tap the timeline to skip to a certain point in the playback. So far so ... bad.

But I searched a lot and did not find any specific guide/idea/hack/... to replace the default video-player with anything more sophisticated.

Of cause, I came across MoliPlayer. This player allows, if used to play videos from INSIDE this specific app, to skip by timeline-tapping.

What I'm looking for is a system-wide replacement for the video-player, so if I stream a video in IE, the replacement opens up and lets me navigate a video like it was possible back in the Stone Age (times of SymbianOS).

Does anyone know if or if not a solution for this problem exists?

In addition, does any of the software-development guys knows, if this is at all possible to be developed for WP8? I quickly searched through MSDN and did not find any usefull information about this. Is there a chance (like for the message app or the camera app) to replace the video-player by your own application in the way I described above?

Comment: AFAIK, and from what I've read, there is no way to replace this. Not 100% sure, though.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to replace the default video player in IE or other system apps - neither by the user nor the developer. You can launch a specific video app from your own app as a dev, but that's all for now.

You can always post suggestions to http://windowsphone.uservoice.com